# Is it valid to start a game without an open gate?

Tags: arkham-horror

Played a game yesterday where, during setup, the first gate was supposed to open on the Science Building.

However, Kate also starts there and her special ability is that gates do not open on her location.

We decided that the game started without any open gates instead of drawing another mythos card for setup. Was this the correct ruling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The only reason you would draw another Mythos card would be if it was a Rumor. Otherwise the first Mythos works just like every subsequent Mythos.